# Passing props to react-redux container component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a react-redux container component that is created within a React Native Navigator component. I want to be able to pass the navigator as a prop to this container component so that after a button is pressed inside its presentational component, it can push an object onto the navigator stack.

I want to do this without needing to hand write all the boilerplate code that the react-redux container component gives me (and also not miss out on all the optimisations that react-redux would give me here too).

Example container component code:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        prop1: state.prop1,
        prop2: state.prop2
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onSearchPressed: (e) => {
            dispatch(submitSearch(navigator)) // This is where I want to use the injected navigator
        }
    }
}

const SearchViewContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(SearchView)

export default SearchViewContainer
```

And I'd want to be able to call the component like this from within my navigator `renderScene` function:

```
<SearchViewContainer navigator={navigator}/>
```

In the container code above, I'd need to be able to access this passed prop from within the `mapDispatchToProps` function.

I don't fancy storing the navigator on the redux state object and don't want to pass the prop down to the presentational component.

Is there a way I can pass in a prop to this container component? Alternatively, are there any alternative approaches that I'm overlooking?

Thanks.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

`mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` both take `ownProps` as the second argument.

```
[mapStateToProps(state, [ownProps]): stateProps] (Function):
[mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps] (Object or Function):
```

For [reference](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api/connect.md#mapstatetoprops-state-ownprops--object)

Answer (score 15):

You can pass in a second argument to `mapStateToProps(state, ownProps)` which will give you access to the props passed into the component in mapStateToProps

Comment: How would I get access to it in mapDispatchToProps?

Comment: @Michael in the same way, you can  use the second argument

Answer (score 7):

There's a few gotchas when doing this with typescript, so here's an example.

One gotcha was when you are only using dispatchToProps (and not mapping any state props), it's important to not omit the state param, (it can be named with an underscore prefix).

Another gotcha was that the ownProps param had to be typed using an interface containing only the passed props - this can be achieved by splitting your props interface into two interfaces, e.g.

```
interface MyComponentOwnProps {
  value: number;
}

interface MyComponentConnectedProps {
  someAction: (x: number) => void;
}

export class MyComponent extends React.Component<
  MyComponentOwnProps & MyComponentConnectedProps
> {
....//  component logic
}

const mapStateToProps = (
  _state: AppState,
  ownProps: MyComponentOwnProps,
) => ({
  value: ownProps.value,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  someAction,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

The component can be declared by passing the single parameter:

```
<MyComponent value={event} />
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using Decorators (@)

If you are using decorators, the code below give an example in the case you want to use decorators for your redux connect.

```
@connect(
    (state, ownProps) => {
        return {
            Foo: ownProps.Foo,
        }
    }
)
export default class Bar extends React.Component {
```

If you now check `this.props.Foo` you will see the prop that was added from where the `Bar` component was used.

```
<Bar Foo={'Baz'} />
```

In this case `this.props.Foo` will be the string 'Baz'

Hope this clarifies some things.