# Trying to use componentWillReceiveProps to change the button color

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I am trying to use componentwillReceiveProps to change the button color.
- when I click the news channel, get top news button should change the color.
- so I thought in Button.js I will use componentwillReceiveProps
- so that after I receive the props I will change the button color.
- but inside componentwillReceiveProps of Button.js nothing is printing.
- I researched and found the below link, but still not helping me
  [How do i use componentWillReceiveProps() correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454340/how-do-i-use-componentwillreceiveprops-correctly)
- can you tell me how to fix it?
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-wu-btlre

```js
    class Button extends Component {
      componentWillReceiveProps(nextprops) {
        console.log("componentWillReceiveProps nextprops--->", nextprops);
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                // getPosts(channel);
                //  getAlert();
              }}
              className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
            >
              Get top news
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: What does the parent of `Button` look like?

Comment: nothing is printing because you are not passing any prop in your `Button` component

Comment: @Rikin in my code snadbox, can you update it like how to achieve with componentWillReceiveProps...its so confusing :(

Comment: Just pass any props to your button and you should be good. If you dont know how to I recommend stepping back and get into react basics to save you headache later. For what it may be worth method that you are after is deprecated

Comment: hey I tried adding props in App.js but still not working :( codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-villani-xyikq can you update in my fiddle, I am stuck with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's your `app.js` from **SandBOX** and its clearly showing you are not passing anything to the button component. That's why its not showing anything.

```
import React from "react";
import ChannelsField from "./ChannelsField";
import RecentChannelItem from "./RecentChannelValues";

import Button from "../containers/Button";
import TopNews from "../containers/TopNews";
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <RecentChannelItem />
    <ChannelsField />
    <Button />
    <TopNews />
  </div>
);
export default App;
```

Comment: in my code snadbox, can you update it like how to achieve with componentWillReceiveProps...its so confusing :(

Comment: @tkkk [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/passing-data-between-react-components-parent-children-siblings-a64f89e24ecf). Use the third method you already doing **Redux** you just need to get data from the store simple.

Comment: @tkkk for that you need to update the store when the channel is clicked and you will get the value everytime its update in the store like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778153/passing-props-to-react-redux-container-component).

Comment: hey looked at aboth of your links, I am trying to achieve it using componentwillreceiveprops can you tell me how to achive using componentwillreceiveprops...it would be great if you in my code sandbox, its so confusing :(

Comment: hey I tried adding props in App.js but still not working :( https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-villani-xyikq

can you update in my fiddle, I am stuck with it